# Python loops in 2d-array

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy

So I have two 1d arrays

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [5,6,7,8,9]
```

and a zero 2d array

```
2d_array=np.zeros((5, 5))
```

I have two equations

```
R = 5*y+1
S = R + 5*x
```

I want to make a loop to find all possible answers for `S` from the different values of `x` and `(y in R)` and store them in the 2d zero array.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you recently ask this same question?

Comment: Use `itertools.product` to generate all the possible x/y combined values.

Answer (score 0):

The most effective way to iterate through two 2d arrays would be to use two for loops.

```
listX = [1,2,3,4,5]

listY = [5,6,7,8,9]

zeroArray = []

for x in listX:
    for y in listY:
        R = 5 * y + 1
        S = R + 5 * x
        tempList = [R, S]
        zeroArray.append(tempList)
```

**Update to second question:**

New Code to find max S value and put the array into a 5x5:

```
listX = [1,2,3,4,5]

listY = [5,6,7,8,9]

zeroArray = []

highestValue = (5 * listY[0] + 1) + 5 * listX[0]

for x in listX:
    tempList = []
    for y in listY:
        R = 5 * y + 1
        S = R + 5 * x
        tempList.append(S)
        if S > highestValue:
            highestValue = S
    zeroArray.append(tempList)
```

This should work.

Comment: That's great, just one more thing, I only need S in the array so I changed this tempList = [R, S] to tempList = [S], Now I want to make it a 5x5 array, how can I do that ? and then how can I locate the max number in that array, for example if it's the first one it would be i0 and j0.  Thank u so much :)

Comment: Sounds good!  If you only want the S, you could just have `zeroArray.append(S)`, because that would be cleaner and not have any extra 3d lists, but if you need that for something, keep it that way

Comment: But now I want to make it a 5x5 array, how can I do that ? and then how can I locate the max number in that array, for example if it's the first one it would be i0 and j0. Thank u so much :)

Comment: What do you want to turn into a 5x5 array?  and for the max number is it the highest S value?

Comment: the ZeroArray, yea I meant the highest S value. Thanks

Comment: @ali you should define your problem in the question, not partly in one of the comments in an answer. Also try to stick to one question per post. You can always ask another question about the max thing.